# Handle unused streams in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, garbage-collection

Supposed I use `http.request` in Node.js to send an HTTP request to a server, but the only thing I am interested in is the status code - to see whether it worked or not. What I am explicitly *NOT* interested in is the response stream.

So, basically my code looks something like that:

```
var req = https.request(options, {
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/'
}), function (res) {
  // Handle res.statusCode
  callback(null);
});

req.write('Some data ...');
req.end();
```

My question now is whether I have to do anything with the `res` stream: Do I have to read it, close it, ...?

Do I need something such as:

```
res.end();
```

or

```
res.resume();
```

or anything like that in order to make sure that the stream is closed and garbage collected properly? Anything to watch out for?

Comment: You have no obligation to write an on('data') listener.  However, you will still be receiving this data in the background, your node application just won't know what to do with it.  The .end() is not for data coming in, .end() is called when you are done sending data to the request.

Comment: No, I won't receive those data in the background (streams2!), as long as I don't run the resume() function. Hence your comment if I understand it correctly does not help :-(

Comment: Just because the "stream" has paused, doesn't mean that the network traffic hasn't occurred... You cannot keep the network traffic from occuring, which is what I was referring to, and yes, res.resume() in this case becomes necessary, specifically for this same reason.  You're essentially telling the stream that "Yes, I know you've received this data, and yes, I really am ignoring it, thank you"

Comment: I don't want the network traffic to 'not happen', I just want the stream to know that I am not interested in its data. Hence, `res.resume()' is actually what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) { 
    //You do not have to write this listener if you don't want to
    //but NOde will still get all the chunks of data, and attempt to
    //call a callback it will find null, and end up discarding every "chunk"

  });

  res.resume();//Omitting the above(empty ondata listener) and including this line, would exhibit almost identical behavior, res.resume() being very slightly more performant.

  //Not there is no res.end(), even in the version that is processing data
  //Calling end() is the job of the sender, not the receiver
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
//req.end() signifies the end of the data that you are writing to the 
//responding computer.
```

http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/01/new-streaming-api-node

See the link above for information as a reference as to why this is now necessary.

Comment: As stated in the comment above, does not help with streams2, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: The only thing you need to add for streams two is the res.resume(), so that you don't need to write your on('data') listener, as you suggested.  All of this is because of my original comment: No matter what you do, you are going to sent this data, and unless you phyisically shut down your process, it will be received.